# Cannot embed image url in Play 2.6 reusable block

Tags: scala, templates, imageurl, playframework-2.6

In Play 2.5.9 , I could embed images in a reusable block.
Since moving to Play 2.6.3 , the images cannot be displayed.
See
https://github.com/raychenon/play-table-of-contents/blob/master/app/views/thankyou.scala.html#L5

Any full image urls on https or http cannot be displayed.

You can have a look at the [app running here](https://testtableofcontents.herokuapp.com/thankyou). The current version running is in [this branch](https://github.com/raychenon/play-table-of-contents/pull/19).

I'm pretty sure I'm missing one key in the `application.conf`. Or any idea how to embed images in Play 2.6 ?

Comment: Check you're not violating the new automatically-applied content security policy headers (see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders#Configuring-the-security-headers).) You can disable the filter entirely by putting `play.filters.disabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"` in your `application.conf`, though it's obviously better to figure out what you need to unrestrict in a more targeted manner.

Comment: Thanks @Mikesname , I tried the filter. It did not work. Neither `play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter` . Thanks for the help